# Limit, isolated, border and interior points of a set $\mathbb{Q}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I have a set $\mathbb{Q}^2$, and I'm trying to determine it's limit points, interior points, border points and isolated points.

My answer is, that it has no border point, no limit point, no interior point and no isolated point.

Is it correct? Seems weird but it makes sense to me.

Thanks

Comment: If the interior and boundary of $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ are both empty, then $\mathbb{Q}^{2}$ is empty. Does that seem right?

Comment: @Mark Didn't realize the implication. Could you help me find the points?

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't just want to give you the answers. Please add some information to the question. Do you know the definitions? How did you arrive at your conclusions?

Comment: @Mark Of course, I want to understand the answers too. Yes, I know the definition. My conclusion for all of the points was that, no matter in which point where we put a ball of arbitrary length, we couldn't guarantee that there would be some point inside it, or that there wouldn't be.

Comment: @Mark because the points in the set are distributed evenly and are not converging / diverging to some value. If that makes sense.

Comment: @Mark But I just realized some of my mistakes. I'm still learning the concepts.

Comment: @Mark I think that isolated points are all of the set. Is that correct? Still not sure about boundary points.

Comment: What topology are you working in? Is this in the ambient $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @user113102 standard metric space

Comment: Can you post the definitions you're trying to use? Like (for example) why do you think that all points are isolated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some careful thought will reveal that *all* points of $\Bbb R^2$ are limit points of $\Bbb Q^2$ and boundary points too. $\Bbb Q^2$ has no interior points, that's right, and no isolated points either. All open balls contain rational points and also contain irrational points.